# Gulp sourcemaps with css minify

Tags: node.js, gulp

I put hours into this and can't really understand what's going on here. I try to `concat`, `minify` and create `sourcemaps` for my css files. I want my folder structure like this:

```
- Assets
----bundles
--------css
----css
----maps
--------css
```

I used lots of variations of the following code but can't get it working. For example when I use the following code:

```
gulp.src("./Assets/css/*.css", { base: "." })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat("./Assets/bundles/css/"))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./Assets/bundles/maps"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
```

This creates a folder structure as:

> ./Assets/bundles/maps/Assets/bundles/css/myFile.css.map

However, when I use

```
gulp.src("./Assets/css/*.css", { base: "." })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat("./Assets/bundles/css/"))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
```

This outputs to my root project folder like

> ./css/Assets/bundles/css/myFile.css.map

What's going on here? I tried to use gulp-rename but couldn't make it work too.

Note: Gulp version is 3.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using it like this

```
gulp.src("./Assets/css/*.css", { base: "." })
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat("./Assets/bundles/css/"))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./Assets/bundles/maps/css", {
            sourceMappingURL: function (file) { //This is to reference the correct paths for our map file..
                return "../maps/css/" + path.basename(file.path) + ".map"; //require the path module..
            }
        }))
        .pipe(rename(function (path) {
            if (path.extname == ".map") { //Only change the paths of map files not the .min files
                path.dirname = "./Assets/bundles/maps/css";
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
```